# How to synchronously retrieve network status for certain transport types as of Android 22?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend, android-connectivitymanager

*I changed the question title since [Kiskae provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60712092/356895) a solution to the broader problem which makes the question about wrapping a callback API needless for the particular problem. The former question title was:*

> How to wrap asynchronous callback into suspend function using Coroutines?

---

I am trying to wrap the [`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) API (>= SDK level 21) of the Android framework into a suspend function to facilitate a synchronous API:

```
private suspend fun ConnectivityManager.isNetworkAvailable(
    vararg transportType: /* android.net.NetworkCapabilities.Transport */ Int)
: Boolean {
    val isAvailable = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Boolean> { continuation ->
        val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        transportType.forEach {
            builder.addCapability(it)
        }
        val networkRequest = builder.build()
        val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                super.onAvailable(network)
                Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "[${Thread.currentThread().name}] onAvailable")
                continuation.resume(true)
                unregisterNetworkCallback(this)
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                super.onLost(network)
                Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "[${Thread.currentThread().name}] onLost")
                continuation.resume(false)
                unregisterNetworkCallback(this)
            }
        }
        Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "[${Thread.currentThread().name}] registerNetworkCallback BEFORE")
        registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback)
        Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "[${Thread.currentThread().name}] registerNetworkCallback AFTER")
    }
    Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "[${Thread.currentThread().name}] return isAvailable BEFORE")
    return isAvailable
}
```

When I call the `isNetworkAvailable(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)` then the following is output:

> [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] registerNetworkCallback BEFORE
>   [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] registerNetworkCallback AFTER

The `onAvailable` and `onLost` are never called, though.

## References

- This is inspired by the [codelabs/building-kotlin-extensions-library/#4](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/building-kotlin-extensions-library/#4). See [`FusedLocationProviderClient.awaitLastLocation()`](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines/blob/fa23733054bffa396d45a949f54acd3e29bfdc38/ktx-library-codelab/step-06/myktxlibrary/src/main/java/com/example/android/myktxlibrary/LocationUtils.kt#L43-L50) for a sample application.

## Related

- [Using Firebase on Android with Kotlin Coroutines](https://joebirch.co/2019/10/03/using-firebase-on-android-with-kotlin-coroutines/)
- [Callbacks and Kotlin Flows](https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf)
- [Cancellation in coroutines](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629)
- [MovieHut/NetworkRepository.kt](https://github.com/cranium44/MovieHut/blob/8f106295c23634fdfe22779a6136232a7479cfb1/app/src/main/java/com/decagon/moviehut/controllers/repositories/NetworkRepository.kt)

Comment: did you add the permissions to Use internet

Comment: Yes, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is in the *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Comment: I hear the coroutine builder function of the day is `suspendCancellableCoroutine`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Did you miss that I use this function in the code snippet?

Comment: Yes. Wasn't sure what else the question could be about than that you need `suspendCancellableCoroutine` for this, whoops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the relevant API for what you want to do isn't async, so coroutines should not be required:

```kotlin
private fun ConnectivityManager.isNetworkAvailable(
    vararg transportType: /* android.net.NetworkCapabilities.Transport */ Int)
: Boolean {
    val network = getActiveNetwork()
    val caps = getNetworkCapabilities(network)
    return caps != null && transportType.all(caps::hasTransport)
}
```

This only requires `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`.

If you want to actively search for a network that has the capabilities required, you will need to use the `requestNetwork` API. (and permission `Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`)

Comment: Thanks for discovering this API. - One remark: you need to invoke `hasTransport` instead of `hasCapability`. - Although, the [`getActiveNetwork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetwork()) API is only available as of SDK level 23 I can combine it with `getNetworkInfo` which has been deprecated.

Comment: You also need to check for `caps == null` as in `return caps != null && transportType.all(caps::hasCapability)` which is the case when you switch of WIFI.

Comment: well this is awesome, nice reference, but unfortunately, for below 23 this needs to add a little condition